# How do I refer to composite component in javascript listener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf-2

I have a JSF2 .xhtml page with a composite component that contains a primefaces p:gmap component.
I am trying to create a javascript listener that will capture zoom events from the google map control.
I have been able to do this when the map is not in a composite component by adding the following javascript listener:

```
                function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    tilt: 0,
                    panControl: false
                };
            google.maps.event.addListener( gmap.getMap(), 'zoom_changed', function() {
                alert('zoom_changed');
                var zoom = gmap.getMap().getZoom();
                var mapZoomUpdate = document.getElementById('mapZoomUpdate');
                mapZoomUpdate.value = ''+zoom;
                changeMapZoomBtn.click();
            });
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

In this case, "gmap" is the primefaces gmap component ID.

However, I am not able to reference the gmap component when it is inside a composite component.
I know I need to add the composite component id as part of the reference, but I do not know the proper syntax.

The component itself is within a form named "formCenter" with prependId="false".
When I look at the page code, I see the reference to the gmap component is:
  id="eventTransactionsMapComp:gmap"

I have tried the following for the addListener reference with no luck:

google.maps.event.addListener( **eventTransactionsMapComp.gmap.getMap(),** 'zoom_changed', function() {

google.maps.event.addListener( **formCenter.eventTransactionsMapComp.gmap.getMap(),** 'zoom_changed', function() {

I thought that maybe I needed to fetch the component ID by using the following type of reference:

google.maps.event.addListener( **document.getElementById('formCenter:eventTransactionsMapComp:gmap').getMap(),** 'zoom_changed', function() {

But that does not work either.

Can anyone help me with the proper syntax to reference the gmap component when adding the listener?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

function findMe() {

```
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function(position) {
                        var map = gmap.getMap(),
                        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                        map.setCenter(latlng);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert(error.message);
                    },
                    {
                       enableHighAccuracy: true
                    });
            }
```

I hope you are useful !!

Lobotex